# What is $_SERVER['HTTP_CB_SIGNATURE'] in coinbase api notification?

Tags: php, webhooks, coinbase-api

Hi I am trying to use coinbase api,api implementation is Working fine but facing problem on notification. Accroding to documentation I have created Notification url and codes are bellow

```
<?php
   require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;


$apiKey=" xxxx";
$apiSecret="xxxx";



$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$raw_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$signature = $_SERVER['HTTP_CB_SIGNATURE'];
$authenticity = $client->verifyCallback($raw_body, $signature); // boolean
if($authenticity){
 $data = json_decode($raw_body, true);
    mail("sahid4745@gmail.com","Coinbase Payment Notifications",print_r($order, true));
}
$message=$raw_body;
mail('sahid4745@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message);



?>
```

But this is producing error as  Notice:

> Undefined index: HTTP_CB_SIGNATURE in /home/exhakduz/api/webhooks.php
>   on line 38

I Don't know actually what is server_cb_signature, if some one can explain that will be great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

All entries in `$_SERVER` that begin with `HTTP_` reflect the contents of HTTP request headers. The header name is converted to uppercase and `-` is converted to `_`. So if the client sends a header like `Foo-Bar: blah`, the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_FOO_BAR']` will be `"blah"`.

The Coinbase documentation says that notifications are secured with a `CB-SIGNATURE` header, so `$_SERVER['HTTP_CB_SIGNATURE']` should contain the contents of this header. I'm not sure why you're not getting it. Your code is exactly like the example code in the documentation.

Maybe there's something in your server configuration that's filtering out nonstandard headers?

Comment: Tnx for your valuable explanation, it was helpful for me but not solved yet,I tried to get datas without verifyCallback and it works, but this way I just get body data, is there anyway to get header data so that I can see exactly what they sent?

Comment: Method found to get headers

Comment: I got header data and cb-signature is something like  "Cb-Signature":"sGIm6VAG5mjWy.............."

Comment: That should be translated into the `$_SERVER['HTTP_CB_SIGNATURE']`, I don't know why it's not working. Maybe there's something in your php.ini preventing it.

Comment: But if you can get the header data some other way, you should be able to use that instead of `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Yes I am going to save extracted signature in $signature, hope that will work.tnx a lot for your help

Comment: I think I got my mistake. This happened  because when I pointed to my notification link I didn’t send any data under Cb-signature, whatever sent that was default datas from my browser only. So server couldn’t find any data that I requested and this error occurred. Hopefully this will be solved if Try to receive a real request from coinbase. Now problem is if 'Cb-signature' not found in header request then do something instead of program aborted  , can you help me to do that plz?by default coinbase library can find matched or not. How do I use condition if  data totally not found?

Comment: CB-Signature isn't something you send, it's something the Coinbase service sends to you.